# is there a way to update multiple row using one update query?

Tags: sql-server

I want to update my `table_1` data to data exist in `table_2` with condition that `table_2.date_modificatio`n is equal to today date

For Example :

```
         Table_1
------------------------------
    id   | Name  | phoneNumber
------------------------------

    1     George     +16742348743

    2     David      +16472379438


          Table_2
----------------------------------------------------------
    id   | Name  | phoneNumber|        Date_modification
-----------------------------------------------------------

    1     George     +19999999999       4/24/2019

    2     David      +11111111111       4/24/2019
```

Assume I have more data that need to be updated . How can I found a way to update the above row each one have different data using just one update query ?

Comment: Your current question is unanswerable.  Please add sample data which explains what you are trying to do here.

Comment: None of the DML statements (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) are limited to a single row. All of them can affect as many, or as few rows as you wish. So, to answer the question in your title "Yes, by using an `UPDATE` statement". You would be better off here showing us what your data looks like (as formatted `text` please), what the results you're after is and showing us your attempts.

Comment: i edited my question . Can you recheck the question please ?@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Please add what code you have tried and we can help fix it perhaps. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: NOTE: by note including the table creation (best in a SQL question) for the tables we must make assumptions there that WILL lead to invalid answers with incorrect assumptions here.

Comment: @davidjoe - Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I would use this update join:

```
UPDATE t1
SET
    Name = t2.Name,
    phoneNumber = t2.phoneNumber
FROM Table_1 t1
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
    t2.Date_modification = CONVERT(date, GETDATE());
```

The logic here is to pull over the name and phone number from `Table_2` to `Table_1`, should there be a matching `id` in both tables, *and* should the modified date in `Table_2` be today.

Comment: Do you not just want the date part? `CONVERT(date, getdate())` NOTE: we both assume the OP has a date type column here....

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss You're right, thanks.  I can never keep all the different SQL APIs straight `\:~|`

Answer (score 0):

The [update](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) statement looks like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

You are specifying the table name, then the columns to be set to their values and then the condition. This updates the records where the condition is met. If the condition is met by more than a single record, then the update will update more than a record.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to update the `phoneNumber` and the tables are joined through `Name`:

```
update t1
set t1.phoneNumber = t2.phoneNumber
from Table_1 t1 inner join Table_2 t2
on t2.Name = t1.Name
where t2.Date_modification = convert(date, getdate())
```

Comment: do you not just want the date part? `CONVERT(date, getdate());` NOTE: we both assume the OP has a date type column here...

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table_2 t2
SET    Name = t1.Name,PhoneNumber=t1.PhoneNumber,Date_modification=getdate()
FROM   Table_1 t1
WHERE  t1.id = t2.id;
```

Please try this in test DB

Comment: This does not rely on the date as requested in the where clause which is what I do believe the OP is asking here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `MERGE` statement. This should work for your example:

```
MERGE table_1 AS target
USING table_2 AS source
ON (target.id = source.id and source.Date_modification = CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 111))
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
    target.Name = source.Name
    ,target.phoneNumber = source.phoneNumber;
```

What it does is:

1. Sets `table_1` to target table and `table_2` to source
2. Checks that the `id` match AND that `Date_modification` is today
3. Updates the `Name` and `phoneNumber` column in target (`table_1`) to what's in source (`table_2`)

I have tried this on the test-data you have provided, but I would recommend running this in a test-environment or in `begin/rollback transaction` encapsulation first, just to be safe.

More info about the `MERGE` statement can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017